# FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF is not supported with table wildcards

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics

I just need to bring the deleted tables from **Firebase tables**. The problem is that I don't know the tables names. So I am using,

```
SELECT * FROM `MyProject.MyDataSet.events_*`
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2022-04-11 08:00:00-04:00'
```

But it is saying,

> FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF is not supported with table wildcards

I know there are some tables deleted but don't know what are these, so how can I know which tables are deleted?

Comment: Can you explain more about your use case? Have you exported data from Firebase to BigQuery?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT it automatically exported from Firebase SDK to BigQuery

Comment: Are the tables deleted directly from Firebase or using BigQuery?